# Selenium with C# SQL Server connection with

Tags: c#, sql-server, selenium

I'm running into an issue when I try to run a simple Selenium script which has field (SSN), and on every new run of the script SSN need to has bigger value (+1). Is it possible Selenium to connect with SQL Server database and check the SSN value from there, and what is the code to connect Selenium with SQL Server database? I am using Selenium with C#. Many Thanks.

Comment: Selenium automates browsers. It do not connect with Database, C# will do that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static int SSN_DB(IWebDriver session, string connString) {
  //creating a db connection connection
  var DBConnection = new SqlConnection(connString);
  DBConnection.Open();
  // Can execute a query or store procedure 
  var MemTable = new SqlCommand();
  MemTable.CommandText = "Select top 1 SSN from dbo.member order by EMPL desc";
  MemTable.Connection = DBConnection;
  var dr = MemTable.ExecuteReader();
  var Memberid = 0;

  while (dr.Read()) {
    Memberid = dr.GetInt32(0);
    Console.WriteLine(Memberid);
  }
  return Memberid;
}

}
```

Comment: SqlConnection have to used in scope of using, otherwise you will endup with memory leak!!!